# Does turbidometeric method count cell number or cell mass?

Tags: microbiology

[image]

Here it says that scattering is inversely proportional to cell number but also says that we can observe greater absorbance as cell number increases.

So does turbidometeric method work on cell mass or number ?

Answer (score 1):

Your text says that scattering is proportional to cell number, which is correct. It is not inversely proportional, as you stated.

Comment: But if counts it under measurement of cell mass and not number ?

Comment: The spec measures the amount of light scattered by a sample, so increasing the number or size of the cells will increase measured absorbance.

Comment: Imagine a room full of flying insects. One could estimate the number of insects in the room by shining a flashlight at one end and observing its brightness at the other end. If the room is densely packed with tiny flies, the flashlight will appear darker from the other side of the room because the flies block the light. A smaller number of butterflies, which make a larger shadow, would block the same amount of light and give the same absorbance. Both the number and size of the insects affect the amount of light transmitted through the room.